How to optimize in MVC Hibernate?
I work with mvc hibernate, postgres, jquery and we use jsp instead of html at my company. We have a lot of data that may go upto millions of rows. We have paginations but still fetching data takes a lot of time. How to reduce it? Are there any general techniques to tackle this?
Also my company doesnt have many good developers and this is my first job so forgive me for my not so polished language.
Its a 6ish years old project!!
Right now we use materialized views (I feel wierd using it because to show recent data in it it needs refreshing and that too takes a lot of time). Our clients always call us complaining about data not loading quickly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
